# XmlException in C#: Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, xml, windows-runtime, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read an XML file in a C# WinRt app when the app resumes:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile File = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("PreviousSession.xml");
if (File != null)
{
    var File2 = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("PreviousSession.xml");
    string Document = File2.ToString();
    System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Document);
}
```

But I get a `System.Xml.XmlException`:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

How can I fix this and read the file properly?

---

My XML document is being constructed like this:

```
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument Document = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement Element = (Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement)Document.AppendChild(Document.CreateElement("PreviousSessionData"));
...
Windows.Storage.IStorageFile TempFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("PreviousSession.xml", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await Document.SaveToFileAsync(TempFile);
```

For a file like this:

```
<PreviousSessionData>...</PreviousSessionData>
```

Comment: Please show your XML File, at least the first few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse` [expects an XML string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not an XML File name.

This code is wrong (see comments) :

```
string Document = File2.ToString();          // Return the name of "File2" object, not File2 content!
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Document);   // Parse error, trying to parse the string "PreviousSession.xml" !
```

What you want is put the content of the file in a string:

```
string Document = File.ReadAllLines(File2);
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Document);
```

Or you can use `XDocument.Load` which [expects a file path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not a string.